# Single command to stop Parallels hypervisor (kernel extensions)

Tags: macos, mac, parallels

I'm using multiple virtualization products on my MacBook Pro (VirtualBox, VMware Fusion, Parallels).
To avoid problems I always make sure only the procesesses/kernel extensions for one of those products are running.

For VirtualBox you can run:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox start
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox stop
```

For VMware Fusion 3:

```
sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/boot.sh --start
sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/boot.sh --stop
```

Is there a single command or script to stop/start the Parallels stuff? Currently I am running multiple 'launchctl' and 'kextunload' commands.

Comment: By the way: VMware Fusion 4 does load/unload of the kernel extensions automatically when you start/stop the application. No boot.sh necessary. The stuff in "/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/" isn't there any more anyway.